# Custom AMI with source code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elasticsearch

In aws how can we create a custom ami which contains both config files and source code? (I want to create an ami with source code for the application embedded in it)

Answer (score 0):

Generally you just

- Start an instance with the base OS you need
- Configure the VM however you like, with code, config, static resources
- Create an AMI either using the console or CLI / API

This will be slow if you need to auto scale, if you need to compile before the server works. Two good approaches are:

- Create a golden AMI that has the application fully installed and configured, ready to go. It starts quickly, but you have to recreate your AMI every time your OS, stack, application or config changes. You really have to do this if you need fast startup times to auto scale to quickly increasing load.
- Create a base AMI that has the minimum you need that rarely changes, then on startup it can update the OS, applications, download either source or a built binary from a repo like S3 or artifactory, then start working. This is obviously slower.